# How map two properties to the same table using mvc 5 and EntityFramework code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have this class....

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> PostsCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> PostsModified { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And the other class is this...

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    [ForeignKey("UserCreated"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string CreatedId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModify"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ModifiedId { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    [InverseProperty("PostsCreated")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> UserCreated { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PostsModified")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> UserModify { get; set; }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public Public Public { get; set; }
}
```

My data acces is this.....

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("BlogLibrary2")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}
```

And I got this error when I try to create a controller using this data acces and the Post class:

There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'LibraryBlog.Models.Post'. The foreign key component 'CreatedId' is not a declared property on type 'ApplicationUser'.Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed that error. I modified this class and now look like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     [Required]
     [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Post> PostsCreated { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Post> PostsModified { get; set; }
     public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And this one:

```
public class Post
{
     public int PostId { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }

     public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
     //---------------------Here is the point
     public string PostCreatedBy { get; set; }
     public string PostModifiedBy { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("PostCreatedBy"), InverseProperty("PostsCreated")]
     public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("PostModifiedBy"), InverseProperty("PostsModified")]
     public virtual ApplicationUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
     //-------------------------------------------
     public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
     public Public Public { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("BlogLibrary2")
    {
    }
        public DbSet<Post> posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; } 
}
```

Would you please edit the code with the above one. Hope this helps..